# how to load html page from another computer on wifi network

Tags: html, wifi

i can load an html page from my computer into my browser using the address:  file:///c:/temp/test1.html.

How would i load an html page from another computer which is on my wi-fi network?
The other computer is connected to the same wifi network as the first.  I would like to be able to type - into the address bar of the browser of the first computer - some address which will load the html file which resides on the second computer.  I know what folder hold the html file of the second computer.
Can I somehow use the local IP address of the second computer as part of the address of the file to be placed in the address bar of the browser of the first computer?

Thank you for helping out.  I appreciate it.

Comment: depends very much on the other computer. Imagine that most users of the other computer might not often want to share. Maybe you can clarify what the problem setup is, i.e. do you run two computers in your wifi?

Comment: scenario is a windows pc and a mac both members of a wireless wifi network. Is there some way, using the local ip address of the mac, to load an html file on the mac into my windows pc browser  - by entering something into the url address field of the windows pc browser.  thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

There are MANY ways to do this.

One way would be to make your temp folder shareable on your network and open it as such.